# how to use Session in middleware with laravel5.2

Tags: laravel, middleware, laravel-middleware

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;

    class OturumKontrolu
    {


        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            if($request->session()->get('yoneticiSifre') && $request->session()->get('yoneticiMail')){
                return redirect('/anakumanda');
            }else{
                return $next($request);
            }
            return redirect('/yonlendirmeHatasi');
        }
    }
```

1. Is this use correct? If not, how are sessions used in the
   middleware?

> return redirect('/yonlendirmeHatasi');

2. is up use correct? Thanks for answers.

Comment: This code will not work.If condition returned false, will work two return, but must be only one.

Comment: The last return will never be reached.

Comment: How should it be?